# setup Zyxel USG 20W as L2TP VPN Server

Tags: vpn, l2tp, zyxel

I have a Zywall USG 20W (wireless disabled) behind a router supplied by my ISP. All ports (both TCP and UDP) on the ISP router are forwarded to the 20W.

I'm trying to configure an L2TP VPN to be used by Windows XP and Windows 7 with Microsoft's native VPN client. This was working before with a different firewall, so I'm pretty sure that all the required packets are flowing to the 20W.

I followed a tutorial from the Italian Zyxel Website, but I cannot get the VPN to work. Always cannot pass phase 2, and I see the following in the log:

> [ID]: Tunnel [Default_L2TP_VPN_Connection] Phase 2 local policy mismatch

Phase 1 goes fine, and in the Windows event logs, the error is always Event ID 788.

This happens regardless the proposals I set in the phase 1 and 2 setting.
What should I check? Is there any way to get more detailed diagnostic info? (Policy mismatch is too generic.)

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? Also: Do you have a link to that tutorial?

Comment: Sorry, but I finally changed the firewall with a Netgear.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I didn't get anywhere either. (Not even past phase 1.) We also use a different VPN  now. Too much time wasted on this already.